# Is it possible to change lifetime scope during runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac, mef

I'm using Autofac in my WebApi project and till now everything has worked fine. For example, I register:

```
builder.Register(x => new LogService())
    .As<ILogService>().Exported(x => x.As<ILogService>()).SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType(typeof(UnitOfWork)).As(typeof(IUnitOfWork))
    .InstancePerRequest();
```

The above works like charm. Note the `Exported`.

However, now I added [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/) so that I can implement a plugin architecture. I've also added [Autofac.Mef](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Mef) so that I can export types registered in Autofac back to MEF.

So to the above Autofac config, I've also added:

```
builder.RegisterType<ImportFactory>()
    .As<IImportFactory>()
    .Exported(x => x.As<IImportFactory>())
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

This factory class just gives me various services that I need depending on the import type (eg. customers, products, etc). These services are all registered as `InstancePerRequest`. The factory class looks like this:

```
public class ImportFactory : BaseService, IImportFactory
{
    public ImportFactory(ILogService logService, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) 
        : base(logService, unitOfWork) { }
}
```

And the plugins look like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IImportPlugin))]
public class ImportCustomers : ImportPlugin, IImportPlugin
{
    private ICustomerService customerService;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ImportCustomers(ILogService logService, IImportFactory importFactory)
        : base()
    {
        this.logService = logService;
        this.importFactory = importFactory;
    }
}
```

Each plugin has a module which allows it to register in Autofac:

```
[Export(typeof(IModule))]
public class AutofacModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<ImportCustomers>()
            .Exported(x => x.As<IImportPlugin>())
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```

Furthermore, from within my controller I start my import job in a separate thread as follows:

```
public class ImportController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IComponentContext componentContext;

    public ImportController(IComponentContext componentContext, ILogService logService) 
        : base(logService)
    {
        this.componentContext = componentContext;
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Start()
    {
        var config = componentContext.Resolve<IPluginConfig>();
        var plugins = config.ImportPlugins;

        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>
        {
            plugins.First().Import(); //Just to test
        });

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

However now I have a mixture of scopes when Autofac injects dependencies because I get the following error

> Unable to resolve the type 'App.Common.Logging.LogService' because the lifetime scope it belongs in can't be located. The following services are exposed by this registration:
>   - App.Common.Logging.ILogService
>
> Details ---> No scope with a tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested.
>
> If you see this during execution of a web application, it generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario). Under the web integration always request dependencies from the dependency resolver or the request lifetime scope, never from the container itself. (See inner exception for details.)

If all types are registered as `InstancePerLifetimeScope` then everything works fine, ie Autofac injects dependencies as expected. However the problem lies when types have different scopes. This is because, for example, `ImportFactory` is `InstancePerLifetimeScope` and it has a dependency on `IUnitOfWork` which is `InstancePerRequest`.

What is the correct registration so that dependencies can be injected correctly without using a secondary container and service location? Would a local scope do the trick?

Comment: Have you [read the docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mef.html)? Autofac.Mef brings MEF components into Autofac, not the other way around.

Comment: @TravisIllig Yes I've read them and I've nearly managed to get it working. I'm adding an Autofac module in every MEF plugin which allows it to register its type with the container. The problem I have is related to different scopes and I can't solve it as the code stands.

Comment: @TravisIllig  If all types are registered as `InstancePerLifetimeScope` then it works. However I don't think this is the correct solution as I'd rather have `SingleInstance` on the `ILogService` and `InstancePerRequest` on the unit of work and all services.

Comment: "I've also added Autofac.Mef so that I can export types registered in Autofac back to MEF." This is where I'm getting hung up. You're going to have bad times trying to go this way. Also, have you tried doing the plugins import thing _not inside_ `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`? Separate thread means "may execute outside the current request," right?

Comment: In the controller, what is `componentContext`? Why service location instead of DI? (Update the code and the question to explain.)

Comment: Do you really need that background-thread? Use `async` instead if possible. You seem to have some let's say questionable choices with registration, lifetimes - lifetimes need to be carefully selected. I think you'd need to post a small but sufficient example.

Comment: @NSGaga It's best practice to use `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` in an ASP.Net application as it informs IIS of background tasks.

Comment: QueueBackgroundWorkItem basically means "spin up another thread independent of the request and try to keep the AppDomain/app pool alive while it is running". It's certainly not "[within the] request lifetime scope" so you should be looking at the dependency resolver (whatever that is) if async isn't an option.

Comment: @StephenKennedy Yes exactly. That is why I'm asking if it's possible to change the types' scope on the fly just for the background thread, and leaving the original scopes as is for all other cases.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono best practice is not to use any background thread unless you really need to, you didn't really read my reply.